# warning C4146 minus operator on unsigned type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, unsigned

I have this code from a library I want to use. On compiling, I get the following warning:

**warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned**

```
inline int lastbit (uint32_t v)
{
  int r;
  static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
    {
      0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
      31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
    };
  r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((v & -v) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
  return r;
}
```

How can I fix it with altering the library as little as possible?

Comment: You could replace `-v` with `static_cast<uint32_t>(-static_cast<int32_t>(v))`.

Comment: `lastbit (uint32_t v)` -> `lastbit (int32_t v)`?  You cast the result of `((v & -v) * 0x077CB531U)` to `uint32_t` anyways and that's the only place `v` gets used.

Comment: Change the parameter type to `int32_t`? Use a less grumpy compiler? `0u-v`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update 2021-05-18:**  An even better solution from [Raymond Chen's blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20210518-00/?p=105225):

```
neg_v = (0 - v)
```

The compiler doesn't warn because unsigned subtraction is well-defined even when the value on the right is larger than the value on the left.  You could write `0u` instead of `0`, but I think the integral promotions will take care of that for you.

**Original Answer Below**

The type for `v` is `std::uint32_t`, which is an unsigned type.  An unsigned type is typically used for indexes and counts, since they can never be negative.

Attempting to flip the sign on an unsigned number is generally suspicious, which is why the compiler gives a warning.  In this case, however, it's safe and well-defined, and the library is relying on details of what exactly it means to flip the sign on an unsigned number.

From the C++11 standard:

> The negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from the 2^n, where n is the number of bits in the promoted operand.  The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand. [Section 5.3.1.8]

[Where the standard says 2^n, it means that literally, even though 2^n can't be represented in an unsigned type of n bits.  The most common way to *implement* this without using a larger type is to flip all the bits and then add one:  `neg_v = ~v + 1;`.]

To convince the compiler that this operation is OK, here, you might try to use a cast.  (Casts should be used only rarely, when you need to force the compiler to treat a value as something other that its natural type.)

```
const uint32_t neg_v = static_cast<uint32_t>(-static_cast<int32_t>(v));
r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((v & neg_v) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

The inner cast asks the compiler to convert `v` to a 32-bit signed integer.  For values of `v` up to 2^31 - 1, this results in the same value.  For larger values of `v`, this will result in a negative value.

But now you're flipping the sign on a signed value (which the compiler will happily do), but it's no longer guaranteed by the standard to do exactly the same thing.  (All modern machines use two's-complement, so in effect, it will give the same result.)

If you wanted to be nit-picky (like me), you could perform the bitwise operations directly on the unsigned value, using the two's-complement trick from above.  Instead of `-v`, you'd have `(~v + 1u)`:

```
r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((v & (~v + 1u)) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

Comment: "But all modern machines use two's-complement, so in effect, it will give the same result." -- Even on two's-complement machines, it's not guaranteed. I do like your second option, but a third one is to simply suppress the warning through a `#pragma` or through project options, and that's the one I'd go for.

Comment: I've spent too much of my life tracking down bugs that could have been found by a compiler warning to advocate for disabling them except in the most extreme circumstances (and then in as tight a scope as possible).

Comment: the `neg_v = ~v + 1` seems to be the only way to make MSVC shutup about this warning without disabling it or causing warnings on other compilers, like a cast to `int32_t` followed by a cast to `uint32_t` could potentially cause (e.g `-(uint32_t)int32_t_min`)