# unary minus operator applied to unsigned type

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I'm reading [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) about De Bruijn sequence, but my problem isn't help with the article but resolving msvc compiler warning:

> warning C4146: unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result
>   still unsigned

Here is code from wikipedia link which produces this warning:

```
unsigned int v;   
int r;           
static const int MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[32] = 
{
  0, 1, 28, 2, 29, 14, 24, 3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17, 4, 8, 
  31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16, 7, 26, 12, 18, 6, 11, 5, 10, 9
};
r = MultiplyDeBruijnBitPosition[((uint32_t)((v & -v) * 0x077CB531U)) >> 27];
```

the warning is generated in `(v & -v)` part.

I'm not 100% sure (yet) how this works I only know I need it but my project is set up to compile cleanly on W4, and this one is pretty annoying, how should I proceed to resolve this warning here?

Could we use `UINT_MIN` trick here somehow? I have not tried anything because I don't want to end up with bad result from function.

my understanding is that `v & -v` is supposed to extract specific bits out.

Comment: The warning is pretty self-explanatory. What would you expect to be the negative of a value that cannot be negative?

Comment: Use `(0U - v)` instead of `-v`. Same numeric value but avoids the warning.

Comment: @RaymondChen hey thanks, do you mean `(v & (0U -v))`? or `(0U & -v)`?

Comment: you can do explicit typecast  as `v & (uint32_t)(-(signed int)v)`, But `((uint32_t)((v & -v) * 0x077CB531U))` casting truncates the multiplication result

Comment: The points is that `0-x` is the same as `-x`. Remember your high school algebra.

Comment: ah yes, I see now, the warning is gone, thank you all for explanation.

Comment: Turns out this is an exact duplicate, same code sequence and everything: [warning C4146 minus operator on unsigned type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892674/warning-c4146-minus-operator-on-unsigned-type)

Comment: interesting, thank you for sharing. It looks like I'm not the only one turning to wikipedia for complex code problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v & -v` is meant to extract the value of the lsb:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<bitset>
int main() {
    for(unsigned i = 1; i < 21; ++i) {
        std::cout <<std::bitset<8>(i)<<": ";
        std::cout<<i<<": "<<(i & -i)<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}


00000001: 1: 1
00000010: 2: 2
00000011: 3: 1
00000100: 4: 4
00000101: 5: 1
00000110: 6: 2
00000111: 7: 1
00001000: 8: 8
00001001: 9: 1
00001010: 10: 2
00001011: 11: 1
00001100: 12: 4
00001101: 13: 1
00001110: 14: 2
00001111: 15: 1
00010000: 16: 16
00010001: 17: 1
00010010: 18: 2
00010011: 19: 1
00010100: 20: 4
```

With unsigned type in two's complement `-v` can be faked with

```
~v + 1
```